# Custom event in a user control

Tags: c#

My user control has a private binding source:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource _bsMyBindingSource;
```

The binding source object supports the List changed event, which is exactly the event I want to catch and use.

```
private void _bsMyBindingSource_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
      {

      }
```

Now... since _bsMyBindingSource is a private member I don't want to expose this event directly (if that is even possible?).

I want my user control to have a OnChange event, which will be invoked when the internal _bsMyBindingSource_ListChanged is invoked.

How can this be done?

Comment: Wouldnt the UserControl just subscribe to the ListChanged event on the BS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to raise your custom event from the `_bsMyBindingSource_ListChanged` handler.

You can keep it as a `ListChangedEventHandler`:

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public event ListChangedEventHandler OnChange;

    private void _bsMyBindingSource_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // if no listeners, OnChange will be null, so need to check
        if(this.OnChange != null)
        {
            this.OnChange(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Or do a custom event type:

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler OnChange;

    private void _bsMyBindingSource_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // if no listeners, OnChange will be null, so need to check
        if(this.OnChange != null)
        {
            this.OnChange(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

Then your page or whatever can listen to this event:

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    private MyUserControl myControl;

    public void MyPage_Load()
    {
        myControl.OnChange += myControl_OnChange;
    }

    private void myControl_OnChange(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ... do something
    }
}
```